# Fitting 2 collection view cell per row (same on all devices)

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, autolayout

I've created a collection view controller and im trying to fit 2 cells per row in two columns. I got it the way i want it running on a iphone 8, but on other devices (plus, 5s, Xs max...) it gets all messed up. Heres a picture of it on iphone 8:!https://imageshack.com/a/img923/3521/DFwwvc.png

Heres how my collection view is set up:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    collectionView.backgroundColor = .clear
    collectionView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10.0,
                                               left: 2.0,
                                               bottom: 10.0,
                                               right: 2.0)

    return nomeItem.count
}//func numberOfItemsInSection
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let celula = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "PronafCollectionCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! PronafCollectionCell

    celula.labelNumeroItem.text = String(indexPath.row+1)
    celula.labelTitulo.text = nomeItem[indexPath.row]
    celula.labelDescricao.text = descricaoItem[indexPath.row]

    return celula
}//func cellForItemAt

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    switch (indexPath.row){
    case 0:
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueDescricao", sender: self)
    case 1:
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueProponente", sender: self)
    case 2:
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueResponsavelTecnico", sender: self)
    case 3:
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueCar", sender: self)
    case 4:
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueImovel", sender: self)
    case 5:
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueDesenho", sender: self)
    case 6:
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueBuscar", sender: self)
    case 7:
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueResumo", sender: self)
    default:
        break
    }//switch (indexPath.row)
}}
```

Comment: Look at `collectionView(_:layout:sizeForItemAt:)`: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdelegateflowlayout/1617708-collectionview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify the width and height of cells, making it proportional on every phone at `sizeForItemAt` from `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width / 2, height: /* your desired height here */)
}
```

**Tips:** You can even make it a little smaller than half the screen, by multiplying values like this:
 `(collectionView.frame.width / 2) * 0.98`, you can also subtract constant values.

I'd suggest setting `UIEdgeInsets` **after** adjusting cells size.

**Note:** The amount of cells per row is calculated based on the amount of cells that fit the `UICollectionView` width. Therefore, having cells with half the width will fit 2 cells per row.

Comment: didnt work for me, it showed all the cells under each other, just one column

Comment: you can also set `collectionView.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0`and make sure to remove your horizontal insets (left and right).

Comment: also make sure to add `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` in your ViewController, like: <#Your View Controller#> : UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout